# want order by LineSubType in pivat column

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(LineSubType) 
                    from TrnsSalaryProcessRegisterDetail 

                    --inner join TrnsSalaryProcessRegister on TrnsSalaryProcessRegisterDetail.SRID=TrnsSalaryProcessRegister.Id
                    --where TrnsSalaryProcessRegisterDetail.LineValue!=null
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
set @query = '
         select a.empid,a.payrollname,a.DepartmentName,s.PeriodName,
            d.*
         from TrnsSalaryProcessRegister s
         inner join mstemployee a on a.id=s.empid
         inner join 
         (
            SELECT SRID,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select SRID,LineSubType, LineValue
                from TrnsSalaryProcessRegisterDetail

            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(LineValue)
                for LineSubType in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
          ) d
            on s.ID = d.SRID where s.PeriodName=''FY2017-Sep'' and a.payrollname=''EmcoStaff'' order by a.empid asc'
            --print(@query)

            execute(@query);
```

Comment: I've downvoted this question because it is messy, hard to read and does not, explicitly, include a question.  It you won't take the time to ask properly, I won't take the time to answer.  I'll remove the vote if you tidy this up.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You seem to need some help with your query. Unfortunately we need some more information to have much of a chance at helping here. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @destination-data formatting on this site takes a bit to learn. I cleaned up the code part but sadly we still have no idea what the OP actually wants.

Comment: I was a bit harsh, which I regret.  Apologies @AbdulRouf.

Answer (score 0):

Just going off of what was provided here, you look like you want an ordered distinct list returned in a concatenated field ... Just add a group by and an order by which should return distinct values for LineSubeType so you likely will no longer need the distinct clause.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(LineSubType) 
                from TrnsSalaryProcessRegisterDetail 
                GROUP By QUOTENAME(LineSubType)
                ORDER BY QUOTENAME(LineSubType)
                --inner join TrnsSalaryProcessRegister on TrnsSalaryProcessRegisterDetail.SRID=TrnsSalaryProcessRegister.Id
                --where TrnsSalaryProcessRegisterDetail.LineValue!=null
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
set @query = '
     select a.empid,a.payrollname,a.DepartmentName,s.PeriodName,
        d.*
     from TrnsSalaryProcessRegister s
     inner join mstemployee a on a.id=s.empid
     inner join 
     (
        SELECT SRID,' + @cols + ' 
        from 
        (
            select SRID,LineSubType, LineValue
            from TrnsSalaryProcessRegisterDetail

        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            sum(LineValue)
            for LineSubType in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p 
      ) d
        on s.ID = d.SRID where s.PeriodName=''FY2017-Sep'' and a.payrollname=''EmcoStaff'' order by a.empid asc'
        --print(@query)

        execute(@query);
```

Comment: Look at line 5 and 6